# Why does tensorlow LSTM takes only the hidden size as input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

In the tensorflow [LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/rnn_cell.html#LSTMCell) cell we only initialize it by number of units (`num_units`) which is the hidden size of the cell. However, the cell should also take an input `x`. And since the underlying operation is a matrix multiplication operation the size of `x` should also play a role in setting up the LSTM weight. So, shouldn't the cell take the size of the input `x` also as an initialization parameter?

Answer (score 2):

LSTM cell (or other types of RNN cells) is just an object you pass to the function such as `tf.nn.rnn`. `tf.nn.rnn` takes cell and data for input.  Cell is called inside of rnn function with the data you've passed to `tf.nn.rnn`.